# Selenium in python: Select a predefined word from a dropdown that is under a span or ul without unique identifier

Tags: python, forms, selenium, dropdown

I have been trying to figure this out and have searched all over but I can't find the answer. I am trying to fill out a form using Selenium in Python. I have done a couple parts of it already but I am stuck on a drop down. I think I may have two problems.

1.) After having Selenium click on the dropdown I can't figure out what the next element should be to interact with.

2.) I can't figure out how to select a value from the list drop down by a predefined name. In this case it would be "Maricopa" for the county dropdown.

In my ideal world I would just be able to pass a county name into the code either from a user inputting it or from a predefined list I generate. It would select that county from the drop down and then allow me to have Selenium click the search button.

What I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.arizonapublicnotices.com/")

time.sleep(2)

burg_but = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button")
burg_but.click() # Click the dropdown menu on the top left


sdate_cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/input")
sdate_cookie.click() # Update start date
sdate_cookie.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a") # Select all pre-existing text/input value
sdate_cookie.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)    # Remove that text
sdate_cookie.send_keys('05/01/2021')


edate_cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/input")
edate_cookie.click() # Update end date
edate_cookie.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a") # Select all pre-existing text/input value
edate_cookie.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)    # Remove that text
edate_cookie.send_keys('05/31/2021')

county_cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='headlessui-listbox-button-5']").click() # Select dropdown for county

# NEED CODE HERE -> SELECT "Maricopa" (or other user defined county from dropdown)


search_but = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[5]/span[2]/button")
search_but.click() # Click search button

search_cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")
search_cookie.click()
search_cookie.send_keys('creditors') # Refine search to specific word "creditors"
```

I have had so many errors I don't know which to post. Most of them are related to not being able to select an element by XPath or not being able to interact with the element I select.

Would love any help. This is my first Question I have posted. I welcome any feedback on how to post my questions better.

David

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get to select the country this way :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)

country = 'Maricopa' <= PASS IN COUNTRY NAME HERE
country_xpath=f"//span[contains(.,'{country}')]"
country_box = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="headlessui-listbox-options-9"]')

for i in country_box:
    actions.move_to_element(i).perform()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(country_xpath).click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pixel!!! I am so happy you responded. I have been pulling my hair out on this one. Here is what is really strange for me. If I use "Maricopa" I get an error: InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[contains('.,Maricopa')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[contains('.,Maricopa')]' is not a valid XPath expression. However, if I use "Gila" or any county in the dropdown list before Gila it works... Any ideas?